# Python Regular Expression Groups

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Why does this regex print `('c',)` and `()`?
I thought `"([abc])+" === "([abc])([abc])([abc])..."`

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
>>> print m.groups()
('c',)
>>> m.groups(0)
('c',)
>>> m = re.match("[abc]+", "abc")
>>> m.groups()
()
>>> m.groups(0)
()
```

Comment: `m.group()='abc'` (it's m.group not m.groups)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation about **[groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups)**

> Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern. The default argument is used for groups that did not participate in the match; it defaults to None.

In the first regex `([abc])+`, it is matching character `a` or `b` or `c` but will store only the last match

```
([abc])+
<----->
Matches a or b or c
Observe carefully. Capturing groups are surrounding only the character class
So, only one character from the matched character class can be stored in capturing group.
```

If you want to capture string `abc` in a capturing group use

```
([abc]+)
```

> Above will find string composed of `a` or `b` or `c` and will store it in capturing group.

In second regex `[abc]+`, there are no capturing groups, so an empty result is shown.

Comment: but `"([abc])([abc])([abc])"` will store all three matches while `([abc])+` will store only the last match. How strange!

Comment: @J.Joe its nothing strange..first one is obvious..i have updated the answer a bit explaining what happens..see if it helps..you can ask if you still have some problem

Comment: @J.Joe `([abc])([abc])([abc])` stores each match in different capturing group..but `(abc)+` will be overwritten every time..so you have only one match stored in capturing group

Comment: This means regex sees `([abc])+` and expand it as `[abc]*([abc])`?

Comment: @J.Joe you can say so..for understanding what is happening behind the hood you can use the debugger mode on **[this](https://regex101.com/r/dD8xR7/1)** site

Comment: Even `Capturing groups are surrounding only the character class`, why is it the last one being stored not the first one or the middle one? Is this documented in some regex standard or varies from language to language?

Comment: @J.Joe data in capturing group is overwritten..so first `a` is matched and stored in capturing group, then it is overwritten by `b`and is stored in same capturing group and finally it is being overwritten by `c`..so finally you are left with `c` stored in capturing group

Comment: rock321987 you rock! `A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.` Got it.

Comment: @rock321987 Shouldn't `re.match()` match only at the beginning of the string? So it should capture `a` instead of `c`. Please help.

Comment: @shiva yes `re.match()` only matches at the beginning of string, but its the capturing group that is storing `c`

Answer (score 0):

When you put plus after the parenthesis you are matching one character at a time, many times. So it matches a then b then c, each time overwriting the previous. Move the + inside ([abc]+) to match one or more.